# Asp.net MVC Custom Client Validation not displaying on screen

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-validators

I am trying to implement unobtrusive client validation for the first time. I feel like I am extremely close, just cannot get the message to display on the screen. If someone can guide me in the correct direction here I would appreciate it. Here is what I have so far.

```
Validation Attribute 
public class WellTestRecordVal : ValidationAttribute , IClientValidatable
{
    private WellTestViewModel record;

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        record = (WellTestViewModel) validationContext.ObjectInstance;


        if (record.WtStartTime > record.WtEndtime)
            return new ValidationResult("This is my server val message.");

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }


    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var startDate = DateTime.Today;

        var rule1 = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        rule1.ValidationType = "startdaterule";
        rule1.ErrorMessage = "this is my iclient val message.";

        return new[] {rule1};
    }
```

I have it applied to to the property on my model as such:

```
[WellTestRecordVal]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss}")]
public DateTime WtStartTime { get; set; }
```

In my bundles I have all the unobtrusive.js and validate.unobtrusive.js files I should need.

My view has the validation on the element.

```
 <label>
                 <span>Start Date</span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.WtStartTime, "{0:yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss}", new { @class = "form-control", @type = "datetime-local", id = "startDate" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.WtStartTime)
                </label>
```

My Jquery for the view is as such.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$.validator.addMethod("startdaterule",
function(value, element, params) {
    var endDate = $("#endDate").val();
    if (value > endDate) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;

});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("startdaterule",function(options) {
    options.rules["startdaterule"] = {};
    options.messages["startdaterule"] = options.message;
});
```

I am using an Ajax.BeginForm on the view.

I can see that the message in my GetClientValidationRules is getting to the view when I inspect it.

What am I missing to get this to display in the view itself? I feel like I am missing some extremely simple that I might have overlooked on the several resources I have reviewed on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach, but for conditional validation I recommend using [foolproof](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=foolproof) validation.

To do this you need to:

1. install [follproof nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/foolproof/)
2. add `mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.js` to your scripts ([get it from here](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof/tree/master/Foolproof/Client%20Scripts))

Then you can use conditional validation like this:

```
public class MyModel 
{
    public DateTime WtStartTime { get; set; } 

    /* I want end time to be greater than or equal to start time */
    [GreaterThanOrEqualTo("WtStartTime", ErrorMessage="End should be >= Start")]
    public DateTime WtEndtime{ get; set; } 

}
```

That's it, you don't need to write your own JavaScript code for client side validation. Just note that you need [ValidationSummary](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-validationsummary) added to your view. You need to add the following line to your view, and it would display the error messages.

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I am not looking for another approach. I am looking for an answer to my question that doesn't need another 3rd party tool. Majority of the javascript is already written anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to narrow down my issue after purchasing the book. Professional ASP.NET MVC 5. My syntax was extremely close. I had two issues. One, I passed no parameter to check my value against. Second, I needed to call `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` before my validation script that I render. It wasn't good enough to just include it. The order matters.